# How can I write a function in OCaml that takes an integer list and return the element with maximum absolute value

Tags: ocaml

I have tried to write code but this only returns max value and not the absolute.

```
let rec maxAbsolutenumber_L l =
    match l with 
    |[] -> None
    |x::_ -> x
    |x::xs -> max x (max_number_list xs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you had a function like `max` except it returns whichever of the two values has the largest absolute value. Seems like that would solve your problem.

You can start, then, by writing this function.

As a side comment, it is not legitimate to return `None` for some calls to a function and an integer value for other calls. They aren't the same type.

As another side comment, the second case of your match will match all nonempty lists. I think you want it to match only lists of length 1. The pattern for such a list is `[x]` (or you can use `x :: []`, which is equivalent).

**Update**

Here is the basic structure for defining a function that has another (helper) function inside:

```
let myfunc a b =
    let helper x y =
        (* Definition of helper *)
    in
    (* Definition of myfunc with calls to helper *)
```

Here's a concrete example, a function that returns the longest string in its input list:

```
let longest_string strings =
    let max_string a b =
        if String.length a >= String.length b then a else b
    in
    List.fold_left max_string "" strings
```

Here is an implementation of the usual `max` function, which might give you some ideas for writing similar functions:

```
let max a b =
    if a >= b then a else b
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to write max function but i am kind of confused as this is first piece of code that i am writing in ocamL. I am trying to learn by seeing resources online but i am npt sure how to add helper methods and how to make the code workable. My question that i am looking solution for is something like this (Write an OCaml function maxAbsoluteVal : int list → int that takes an integer list l and returns the maximum absolute value of l.) and i am trying to gather resources to complete it.